# EOF Error :: when docker command is executed

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I'm trying to setup docker env on my windows 7 system ,
whenever i run docker commands ,i'm getting EOF error.
Any suggestion to solve this issue ?

```
$ docker ps
An error occurred trying to connect: Get 

https://22.222.201.93:2376/v1.21/containers/json: EOF

jayanth@mycomputer MINGW64 ~
$
jayanth@mycomputer MINGW64 ~
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
An error occurred trying to connect: Get https://22.222.201.93:2376/v1.21/version: EOF
```

Comment: What boot2docker version do you have?

Comment: boot2docker version 1.9.1, latest version of Docker toolbox was used for installation .

Answer (score 1):

Try your installation again, this time avoiding cygwin or any bash completely.

In a regular CMD sesion, copy [`docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe`](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.6.0-rc2/docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe) anywhere you want as `docker-machine.exe`.

Type (in the same folder where you copied `docker-machine.exe`):

```
docker-machine ls
docker-machine rm <the machine name from ls>
docker-machine create
docker-machine start
docker-machine ssh
```

In that ssh session, type `docker info` and `docker version` to check if that is working as expected.

If you have a proxy, you want to create a machine with the proxy specified:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox \
--engine-env HTTP_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy.server.com>:<port> \
--engine-env http_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy.server.com>:<port> \
--engine-env HTTPS_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy.server.com>:<port> \
--engine-env https_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy.server.com>:<port> \
--engine-env NO_PROXY=<.server.com>,.sock,localhost,127.0.0.1,::1 \
--engine-env no_proxy=<.server.com>,.sock,localhost,127.0.0.1,::1 \
<container_name>
```

Comment: issues is solved , now not able to set the proxy & pull docker image .some other characters are getting added by default which docker file created ..
docker@default:~$ ls
←[0;0mDockerfile←[0m
docker@default:~$

Comment: i added the proxy in  /var/lib/boot2docker/profile & now able to pull the images , thanks a lot ...

Comment: @Jayanth No: that will not persist when the machine shuts down. You need to create it with the parameters I mention in the answer. That will modify `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` for you.